# Does std::vector::reserve guarantee that the implementation will not invalidate iterators in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdvector

Here is a function which intends to:

a) accept a vector of int

b) for each int in the input vector, append the inverse of this int

preconditions: none

postconditions: returned vector's size() is exacly 2 * the input vector's size.

Note that the vector is modified in-place.

### Question:

Is this function strictly defined behaviour vis-a-vis iterator invalidation during the transform?

### Bonus:

Is there a better/more succinct/robust way to write it?

### Code:

```
std::vector<int> append_negatives(std::vector<int> v)
{
    v.reserve(v.size() * 2);
    std::transform(begin(v), end(v), 
                   back_inserter(v), 
                   [](auto&& x) { return -x; });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Why would you think it might invalidate the iterators?

Comment: What iterators are you speaking of? In the sense of iterators created before a call to append_negatives, those will be invalidated if the vector's reserved size got changed by push_back. reserve() itself will not affect any iterators.

Comment: @Joducus He's passing the vector by value, so nothing in the original gets changed by this function call.

Comment: @Jodocus no I mean the iterators taken just before the call to std::transform

Comment: It's worth noting that doing `resize` instead of `reserve` and killing off the `back_inserter` is generally significantly faster for types with trivial default constructor, as you are removing the check for capacity and the size update from the core of the loop, and everything boils down to direct pointer access. Yes, the compiler in theory could optimize bla bla but in practice I've never seen it do that, doubly so with non-local objects (that make aggressive optimizations way more complicated).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As long as you don't exceed preallocated capacity no reallocation should happen and no references or iterators referring to vector items should get invalidated. However since iterator returned by `end()` does not refer to any vector items it may still get invalidated.

> 23.3.11.3 vector capacity **[vector.capacity]**
>
> 6. ...No reallocation shall take place during insertions that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of `capacity()`

...

> 23.3.11.5 vector modifiers **[vector.modifiers]**
>
> 1. ...If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.

Comment: re the: 2nd quote, can this cause the invalidation of the `end` iterator ?

Comment: @RichardCritten oh! nice catch

Comment: @RichardCritten Though I'm struggling to point the reference in standard for `end()` case I think that by "all the iterators and references" the given quote implies "all the iterators and references to the elements of vector" and since `end()` iterator is not an iterator the element of vector the `end()` iterator may still get invalidated, just like in case of `swap` for example: " [Note: The end() iterator does not refer to any element, so it may be invalidated. —end note ]".

Comment: Yes, `push_back` invalidates `end()`.

Answer (score 4):

The part about the iterator invalidation rules has already been covered, so I'll take this occasion to humbly question the need to use all this machinery (with its delicate rules) for such a trivial problem. You may also consider this a stab at the

> #### Bonus:
>
> Is there a better/more succinct/robust way to write it?

part of the question.

---

Honestly, I'd sidestep the problem completely with the advanced technology of `for` loops. [KISS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

```
std::vector<int> append_negatives(std::vector<int> v) {
    size_t sz = v.size();
    v.resize(sz*2);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) v[i+sz] = -v[i];
    return v;
}
```

Not everything must be obfuscated in a deep cloak of STL algorithms. This is both shorter, IMO more readable and avoids the headaches about iterators invalidation.

Also, unless compilers have gotten extra smart since last time I checked, this is significantly faster, as avoids all the overhead of `push_back` (check if capacity is enough and increment size at each iteration), which is replaced with straight pointer access (*one* assembly instruction); the slim and simple loop body gives better chances for automatic unrolling. I expect this to be faster to compile as well, as we avoid instantiating a bunch of templates.

Mind you, the speed advantage/no invalidation headache can be obtained even with the `transform` benemoth:

```
std::vector<int> append_negatives(std::vector<int> v) {
    size_t sz = v.size();
    v.resize(sz * 2);
    auto beg = begin(v);
    std::transform(beg, beg + sz, beg + sz, 
                   [](int x) { return -x; });
    return v;
}
```

but I fail to see any advantage of this kind of overly verbose code over a plain `for` loop, unless you are paid by the number of "cool" C++ features you manage to squeeze in your code.

---

@MikeMB asks about types that are costly to default-construct; in that case, an explicit `push_back` is fine:

```
std::vector<int> append_negatives(std::vector<int> v) {
    size_t sz = v.size();
    v.reserve(sz*2); // optional
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) v.push_back(-v[i]);
    return v;
}
```

You could also use a range-based for loop if the `transform` in the original post was valid:

```
std::vector<int> append_negatives(std::vector<int> v) {
    v.reserve(v.size()*2);
    for(int &x: v) v.push_back(x);
    return v;
}
```

which is *way* nicer on the eyes than the transform-based solution, but I see in the comments that there's still no consensus about the end iterator invalidation, so this would be just as invalid.

Comment: Thanks for applying some common sense. Of course that method only advantageous for cases where the elements can be cheaply default inserted.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, as a C++ neophyte, you have no idea how much your answer helps. I'm often conflicted as I've read many times on SO and other places _"Use the STL!!!! No matter what!!!!!"_ When I encounter a situation such as the one presented here, my initial instinct is to write a for loop and I somehow feel bad because I didn't initially think of STL.

Comment: @JosephWood: STL algorithms suffer a bit from the [jQuery syndrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif) - some people are so in love with the idea itself that think that they should be used even in cases where using straight core language is better under every aspect. Don't misunderstand me - having a sort, a binary search, heap primitives, random shuffle - stuff that actually does something non-trivial - is fantastic; even trivial algorithms such as copy/copy_n are useful because, although they are verbose, they are still more compact than the hand-made loop, and they express intent. But...

Comment: ... stuff like `std::transform` or `std::for_each` don't really add anything over a plain loop, and require a verbose functor to plug in to actually accomplish something useful - plus insertor iterators if you aren't transforming over an existing sequence. At this point, you are just combining primitive blocks with horribly verbose syntax instead of combining primitive blocks with nice syntax in the language itself. IOW, once your library wants to be *that* general, you are left with an ["inner platform"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect), generally not a good place to be.

Comment: @RichardHodges: yep, it's a thing that I always thought would be useful; worth saying that, in the general case, one would need to be extra careful not to use `operator[]` + assignment, but either `operator[]` + placement `new` or some other helper method entirely.

Comment: @MatteoItalia ` template<class Generator> iterator vec.generate_append(std::size_ items, Generator g);` is probably the cleanest way